# Getting the average and proportion of a column of a dataframe with respect to two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (`df`) with 4 columns: Age, Request_ID, Gender and Type. My values look like the following:

```
Age  Request_ID  Gender Type  
 20           1  M      A  
 28           2  F      B  
 30           1  M      C  
 50           7  M      A  
 19          20  F      B
```

Now I want to get the average Age based on Gender and Type and the number of different Request_ID (the proportion) per Gender and Type in a new dataframe.
For example, the expected outcome would be something like:

```
Gender Type Average_Age Sum_Req_IDs  
F      A           24.5          50  
M      A             40          23  
F      B           23.7         100  
M      B           35.3         200  
F      C           29.1          30  
M      C           30.4          98
```

My code so far is:

```
df.groupby(['Gender','Type'],as_index = False)['Age'].mean()
```

But this returns only the average age.
Could you please help me complete this?

Comment: With Excel you would use a PivotTable to solve this. DataFrames have also something like pivot tables. Give it a search. (Could you please format your question, e.g. put your Dataframe in a code block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) for aggregate column `Age` by `mean` and column `Request_ID` to [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Gender','Type'],as_index=False).agg({'Age':'mean', 'Request_ID':'nunique'})
#if necessary rename columns
df = df.rename(columns={'Age':'Average_Age','Request_ID':'Sum_Req_IDs'})
print (df)
  Gender Type  Sum_Req_IDs  Average_Age
0      F    B            2         23.5
1      M    A            2         35.0
2      M    C            1         30.0
```

Another possible solution is use `nested dict` for `aggregation` - output is `MultiIndex` in `columns` where is necessary remove top level by [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['Gender','Type']).agg({'Age':{'Average_Age': 'mean'}, 
                                       'Request_ID':{'Sum_Req_IDs':'nunique'}})
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Gender Type  Sum_Req_IDs  Average_Age
0      F    B            2         23.5
1      M    A            2         35.0
2      M    C            1         30.0
```

EDIT:

For me a bit unclear if `Request_ID` is aggregate properly, so data are changed for better sample:

```
print (df)
  Age  Request_ID Gender Type
0   20           3      M    A
1   28           3      F    B
2   30           3      M    C
3   50           3      M    A
4   19          20      F    B

#nunique - number of unique values per Gender and Type groups
df1 = df.groupby(['Gender','Type'],as_index=False).agg({'Age':'mean','Request_ID':'nunique'})
print (df1)
  Gender Type  Request_ID   Age
0      F    B           2  23.5
1      M    A           1  35.0
2      M    C           1  30.0

#nunique - number of all values per Gender and Type groups
df2 = df.groupby(['Gender','Type'],as_index = False).agg({'Age':'mean', 'Request_ID':'size'})
print (df2)
  Gender Type  Request_ID   Age
0      F    B           2  23.5
1      M    A           2  35.0
2      M    C           1  30.0

#nunique - sum values per Gender and Type groups
df3 = df.groupby(['Gender','Type'],as_index = False).agg({'Age': 'mean', 'Request_ID':'sum'})
print (df3)
  Gender Type  Request_ID   Age
0      F    B          23  23.5
1      M    A           6  35.0
2      M    C           3  30.0
```